# Get comment count on posts across site

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

I have a site with lots of pages of content and a Facebook comment box (social plugin) on each one. Say, http://subdomain.site.org

I want to build a widget that searches that subdomain for the pages with the most comments on them and list them. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its pretty easy to get the count of comments for each url

use fql:

```
SELECT url, comment_count, FROM link_stat WHERE url = " http://subdomain.site.org"
```

you can also get the comment count on all the urls at the same time (depending on how many urls)

```
SELECT url, comment_count,  FROM link_stat WHERE url in ("url1", "url2", "url3" ... )
```

from facebook -`FQL can handle simple math, basic boolean operators, AND or NOT logical operators, and ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses.`

fql does not support CONTAINS() or anything else like that to use for searching all url's from a subdomain.

see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) for the link_stat table - you can only query on column's that are indexable

Comment: This gives me something that looks like
`[{"url":"http:\/\/subdomain.site.org","comment_count":20}]`
However, it doesn't tell me which of my pages have comments, it just gave me an overall count?

Comment: you have to make the call for each page, or use the second query and put each page's url in the ()

Comment: Ah, ok. So I can do this per page individually, but if say I have 1000 pieces of content, I'd need to pass in each of those 1000 URLs into that second query. There's no query where I can just give it http://subdomain.site.org and it gives me comment counts for any pages found on that subdomain?

Comment: Ah interesting. Knew there were limitations to the language but didn't know if there was a table or something I may have been missing. Thanks for the prompt responses!